# Нарисовать функцию с одним параметром

Tags: c++-cli

Ситуация такая

Есть такие методы,где T это входной параметр,который вводится с клавиатуры(к примеру T=4)

```
public:static double fn(double T,double x)
           {
               if (x>=0)
                   return T;
               else if(x<0)
                   return 0;  
           }

public: void drawfunc(double T)
            {
                double xmin = -5;
                double xmax = 10;
                for(double x = xmin;x<xmax;x+=0.01)
                {                            
                    chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(x,fn(T,x));
                }                                       
            }
```

Они рисуют вот такой график функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужно чтобы метод был с одним параметром и рисовал также как и с 2-мя параметрами
Однако если я его делаю с одним параметром,а 2-ой делаю локальной переменной.

```
public:static double heviside(double T)
       {
           double x=0;
           if ( x>=0)
               return T;
           else if(x<0)
               return 0;          
       }

public:void draw(double U,double T)
       {
           double xmin=-5;
           double xmax=10;
           for(double x=xmin;x<xmax;x+=0.01)
               chart1->Series["Line"]->Points->AddXY(x,heviside(T));
       }
```

То график функции рисуется таким образом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ВОПРОС!

Как можно сделать так,чтоб функция рисовала 1-ый график но c 1-им параметром функции fn(double T)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Параметр `x` не может быть константой, если вы хотите чтобы график не был прямой линией.

Во втором варианте у вас вот что:

```
static double heviside(double T)
{
    double x=0;   // x - константа и равна 0
    if(x>=0)      // это условие всегда выполняется
       return T;  // поэтому всегда выполняется только эта ветка
    else if(x<0)
       return 0;          
}

public:void draw(double U,double T)
{
    double xmin=-5;
    double xmax=10;
    for(double x=xmin; x<xmax; x+=0.01)
        chart1->Series["Line"]->Points->AddXY(x, heviside(T));
        // вы взываете hevisible в цикле, при этом T
        // тоже не меняется, в итоге вы заполняете график
        // одними и теми же числами
}
```

Comment: Да-да T не меняется, потому что это координата от которой и будет продолжение графика единичной функции.
Она у меня как была например 4 так и остаётся ей так как это координата,от которой происходит изменения графика.

В 1-ом случае где 2 параметра там тоже T не меняется но всё строится,но там 2-ой параметр x,который и помогает в изменении графика.